# Woocommerce Alphabetical Listing onclick

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Issue is like i used A-Z listing plugin for woocommerce to display the products in alphabetical order and it's work greate but issue is when i uploaded my 10,000 products on it then the page is not loaded obovusily so is there any other plugin or something to help or any link where can i find out the plugin.

So in basically i want a plugin or code which just show a product which alphabet is select.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: okay i try and tell you.

Comment: I want this type of plugin http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-alphabetical-search/full_screen_preview/9664040?_ga=1.109922757.1764127989.1485333934

Comment: is there any free plugin as per given output or anything ?

Comment: i tried lot to find out the plugin for trial version but no any success :)

Comment: Now try this : https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wp-alphabet-listing-plugin-list-all-wordpress-posts-or-pages-alphabetically-4873
Use type as product

Comment: some of the plugin is working but i have to display only one alphabet products per click because 10,000 products can't load directly. thanks for help i am developing custom page for it.